# SMS Broadcast Receiver without Manifest

Tags: android, android-intent

Wondering how I would go about creating an SMS Broadcast Receiver without using the Manifest file. So for instance, this is my current manifest file line:

```
<receiver android:name="com.paradopolis.randomnotifications.SMSListener">
        <intent-filter>
          <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
       </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

and it's working fine, but I'd like to be able to remove the line and register my broadcast receiver within my service like:

```
registerReceiver(new SMSListener() , [?????]);
```

but I can not find the Intent filter to use, since SMS_RECEIVED is part of the Telephony package. So the question is: What is that intent filter?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create `IntentFilter` in your java file, then `registerReceiver(Receiver, IntentFilter)`

The action will be `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` as a string.

```
IntentFilter i = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
registerReceiver(new SMSListener() , i);
```

Comment: Perfect, didn't realize I could just convert those directly to strings like that, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
    mSmsReceiver = new SMSreceiver();
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
    filter.setPriority(IntentFilter.SYSTEM_HIGH_PRIORITY);
    filter.addAction(SMS_RECEIVE_ACTION); // SMS
    filter.addAction(WAP_PUSH_RECEIVED_ACTION); // MMS
    this.registerReceiver(mSmsReceiver, filter);

    class SMSreceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (!getSMSBlockEnable()) {
            return;
        }

        if (TextUtils.equals(intent.getAction(), SMS_RECEIVE_ACTION)) {

            Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
            if (bundle == null) {
                return;
            }
            Object[] messages = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");

            SmsMessage smsHeader = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])messages[0]);
            if (smsHeader != null) {
                mReceiveNumber = smsHeader.getOriginatingAddress();
                if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mReceiveNumber)) {
                    mReceiveNumber = INVALID_NUMBER;
                }
            }

           for (Object message : messages) {
                SmsMessage sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[])message);
                  if (sms != null) {
                    body.append(sms.getDisplayMessageBody());
                  }
          }
          mReceiveBody = body.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't help me since the constant SMS_RECEIVE_ACTION isn't defined in that code :S

Comment: This answer probably will help other users, the constant is defined at Telephony.Sms.Intents.SMS_RECEIVED_ACTION