# Receive Broadcast while activity is not active

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I wanted to intercept an incoming message so I created a class extending BroadcastReceiver(as given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11306150/read-and-display-incoming-message-text-android)) it worked but as I wanted to control the receiver(stop it when required) I implemented [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7439041/how-to-unregister-broadcastreceiver) but now when I exit the activity the receiver doesn't work.

How to implement the receiver such that it can be controlled and receive broadcast when the activity is not running?

Mainactivity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Button StopB;
    IntentFilter STARTER;
    final BroadcastReceiver MSgR=new BR();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        StopB=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        final BroadcastReceiver MSgR=new BR();
        STARTER=new IntentFilter();
        STARTER.addAction("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        registerReceiver(MSgR, STARTER);

    StopB.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.i("Pressed", "UNRGSTR");
            unregisterReceiver(MSgR);
        }
    } ) ;


    }
```

BR.java

```
  public class BR extends BroadcastReceiver{
String TAG="DELETE BLOCK";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        // do something here
         }
```

Manifest

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.delete_sms_2.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name="BR"></receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4):

define when the receiver will start, you define when activity start then recive work, you need to change in menifest file , as like in this intent filter when sms recived, as like you change it accourding to ur need thanks

```
 <receiver android:name=".HellowordActivity" >
            <intent-filter > 
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/> 
            </intent-filter> 
    </receiver>
```

Comment: if i do that i cant unregister receiver

Comment: you can do any thing in BroadcastReceiver . one time controller goes to ur BroadcastReceiver and match conditions , it depends upon you how you will use it

Comment: if u don't want to add reciver that there is other method to do like that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16182314/sms-broadcast-receiver-without-manifest

Comment: the solution u mentioned works well but as i have mentioned earlier i wanted to unregister the receiver thats why i used the message of the second link.i am bale to receive the Broadcast in both the cases but in first i cant unregister and by the method of second link i am able to unregister but as the scope of the Broadcast object ends when i exist the activty the whole motive of receiving Broadcast is undone

Comment: insert unregisterReceiver in prefrence file and call when u want

Comment: what is preference file ?. I used unregisterReceiver(onclick) it works when i used the solution u suggested the receiver still receives the Broadcast even after calling unregisterReceiver.

Comment: it will goes every time and at there you use if else condition , according to me it can't stop , i can be wrong but it will goes every time

Comment: the problem as far as i see is that the way u suggested <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/> the class that extends Broadcast receiver is bound to be invoked independent of activity. but when we use the way i mentined in the mainactivity class above the scope of the receiver perishes as the activity exits by the solution u suggested the receiver is invoked at the manifest level that why i am having difficulty to unregister it